# How can I use fixed << setprecision(2) only ONCE? Or at least restore to default behaviour?

Tags: c++, std, fixed, cout

This is inside of a display function.  I want to print the weight using 2 decimal points.  Outside of this code block, I don't want setprecision to be in effect.  For example, 777.555 and 444.2222 should display correctly.

```cpp
// Detect if train has cargo:
if (cargo_unit)
{
    // If cargo exists, print output:
    cout << **fixed << setprecision(2);**
    cout << "   Cargo: " << cargo_unit->getDesc() <<
    endl << "  Weight: " << cargo_unit->getWeight() << endl;
}
```

Problem is, once I used fixed << setprecision, I can only reset it to a number like 5 or 6 and then get this:

```
777.555000
444.222200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the previous flags and precision, and then restore them afterwards, eg:

```
// Detect if train has cargo:
if (cargo_unit)
{
    // If cargo exists, print output:

    std::ios_base::fmtflags old_flags = cout.flags();
    std::streamsize old_prec = cout.precision();
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);

    /* alternatively:
    std::ios_base::fmtflags old_flags = cout.setf(std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield);
    std::streamsize old_prec = cout.precision(2);
    */

    std::cout << "   Cargo: " << cargo_unit->getDesc() <<
    std::endl << "  Weight: " << cargo_unit->getWeight() << std::endl;

    cout.precision(old_prec);
    cout.flags(old_flags);
}
```

Comment: ios_base::fmtflags not std::fmtflags

Otherwise this works.  Thanks.

Comment: @DanielPaulGrechPereira fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::defaultfloat` to reset `std::fixed`.

Visit [this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach using std::cout.precision() to save default precision before changing it to 2, and then restoring it back to the default once as and when desired.

```
...
// save current precision
std::streamsize ss = std::cout.precision();

// Detect if train has cargo:
if (cargo_unit)
{
    // If cargo exists, print output:
    cout << **fixed << setprecision(2);**
    cout << "   Cargo: " << cargo_unit->getDesc() <<
    endl << "  Weight: " << cargo_unit->getWeight() << endl;
}

// Restore saved precision
std::cout << std::setprecision(ss);
...
```